# Как закодировать кирилицу в url на golang?

Tags: golang

Есть слово на русском. Нужно, что б программа на golang выдала это-же слово в формате закодированном в url ,т.е. %23%45%67 -типа такого. Как это сделать?

Comment: google://urlencode golang, ленивая соня

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
package main


import (
    "net/url"
    "fmt"
)


func main() {
    fmt.Println(url.QueryEscape("абракадабра"))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Если хочешь чтобы совпадало с версией JS(encodeURIComponent())
То:

```
import "net/url"


func UrlEncoded(str string) (string, error) {
    u, err := url.Parse(str)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return u.String(), nil
```